# Does the arch linux pacstrap utility put any information about the host into the assembled system

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, pacman, disk-image

As part of a prototype arch linux image generation script (which can be seen [for code review here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192125/arch-linux-installation-script-to-be-reviewed-for-any-leakage-of-personal-secu)), I use the normal pacstrap utility to populate a file-system with a bootable install and additional packages.

**What information about the host is used for this / included in the new file-system install?**

My primary concern is in inadvertently releasing security or identifiable information when I upload or distribute a generated file-system image.

My secondary concern is that the file-system image is in some way tailored to my hardware (beyond 64bit amd/intel) and so would be unable to boot or operate normally on other equipment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon examining both a minimal test image generated that uses pacstrap and looking at the pacstrap help, at least the following information seems to be moved onto the new system:

- package repository lists and their identity authentication.
- you pacman [keyring](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Package_signing) (which is a web of trust style authentication.

Both of these can at least leak some identification information and the keyring could include your identity depending on your previous activity.

If you have a private/organisational package repository that is either a local mirror to speed up operations / reduce internet traffic or contains 'approved' packages then you mirror list provides internal networking details.

Your pacman keyring could either contain a link to your [GnuPG](https://www.gnupg.org/) public key or someone else's from your organisation for packages that are unique to you / your company.  Allowing access to and analysis of your key ring can allow an attacker to find uncommon keys as a likely originator identification of the image.

Most of this probably only matters for organisations that have a policy of attack mitigation (reduce the amount of unnecessary information irrespective of apparent risk as a simple risk reduction measure since it is hard to predict with accuracy what might become important).

The pacman help provides you with a way to not move these over:

```
$ pacstrap -h
usage: pacstrap [options] root [packages...]

  Options:
    -C config      Use an alternate config file for pacman
    -c             Use the package cache on the host, rather than the target
    -G             Avoid copying the host's pacman keyring to the target
    -i             Avoid auto-confirmation of package selections
    -M             Avoid copying the host's mirrorlist to the target

    -h             Print this help message

pacstrap installs packages to the specified new root directory. If no packages
are given, pacstrap defaults to the "base" group.
```

So the -G and -M options will prevent copying over this information, however you will have to re-populate these on the new installation.  A new keyring can be generate using:

```
pacman-key --init && pacman-key --populate archlinux
```

An 'appropriate' mirror list (whatever that means for a given situation) can be prepared and placed at /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist